# Is there an easy way of keeping i18n message files in sync?

Tags: grails, internationalization

I am wondering if there is an easy way of keeping different i18n files in sync, so when adding a key/value in messsage_aa.properties would result in the same line in a message_bb.properties file? But this offcourse using a different value..

I would really like to have the same key on the same line number in each of my message_xx.properties file..

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature depends on your IDE.

As an example, I use [ResourceBundle plugin](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/node/413975#.UOYTt-T8LT4) in Eclipse that partially do what you are asking.
"Partially", because it keeps the same order but not necessary the same line (i.e. it doesn't skip line to match one file with another).

Comment: I am using intellij and it more or less does exactly what you mention, i am looking for a solution that actually holds the same line, but at the end maybe a sort of the keys could solve partially my challenge